# stream block in java socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

in a part of my code i write in socket from server and wait to red it from client but client never read this integer that i sent from server and program blocks.
i tested and i see that server sent the integer but i coudn't find why client doesn't receive the integer.
i wrote my code here. note that i commented  important part of code that is about transfer "mysize" variable from server to client like "//*********//"

thank you.

my server part(important line is line 107):

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.im.spi.InputMethod;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * 
 */

/**
 * @author Sina
 *
 */
public class BoxServer {

    ServerSocket serversocket;
    static ThreadHandler t[]=new ThreadHandler[1000000];
    static int size=0;
    static ArrayList<Message> messagebox=new ArrayList<Message>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(79);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.exit(0);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true)
        {

        try{




                //InetAddress inetadress=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                //System.out.println(inetadress);
                //System.out.println(inetadress.getHostName());
                //System.out.println(inetadress.getHostAddress());
                Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();
                if(socket==null)
                {
                    System.out.println("null");
                }
                t[size]=new ThreadHandler(socket,size);
                size++;
                t[size-1].start();



        }
        catch(UnknownHostException e){
        //  System.out.println("salam s");
            System.exit(0);
         //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.exit(0);
        //  System.out.println("bye s");
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


        }

    }

}

class ThreadHandler extends Thread{

    private int mysize;
    Socket mySocket;
    ObjectInputStream inp;
    ObjectOutputStream outp;
    public ThreadHandler(Socket s,int size)
    {

        this.mySocket=s;
        this.mysize=size;
        System.out.println("Actives: " +Thread.activeCount());


    }
    public void run()
    {
        try {

            inp=new ObjectInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());
            outp=new ObjectOutputStream(mySocket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("yaaaani minvise ? :|");
            outp.writeInt(mysize);//*********//
            System.out.println(mysize+"neveshte shod dar systam");
            System.out.println("age in umad yaaani nevesht");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.exit(0);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(true)
        {
        //System.out.println("thread run");
        //System.out.println(mySocket.getLocalPort());
        //System.out.println(mySocket.getLocalAddress());

        try {
        //  System.out.println("my socket:"+mySocket.getOutputStream());
        //  System.out.println(mySocket.isConnected());
        //  System.out.println(inp.available());
        //  System.out.println("inp = "+inp);

            if(mySocket.isConnected())
            {


            Message mess=(Message)inp.readObject();

        //  System.out.print("mess is ====>");
        //  System.out.println(mess+"        ");
        //  JOptionPane x=new JOptionPane();
        //  x.setVisible(true);
        //  x.setMessage(mess);
            //System.out.println("dsd");
            //System.out.println("mess: "+mess);

            if(mess.getReceiver().equals("system-use:code=1"))
            {
            //  System.out.println("yaroo payamasho mikhad");
                String senderOfSystemUse=mess.getSender();
                ArrayList<Message> tempInbox=new ArrayList<Message>();
                for(int i=0;i<BoxServer.messagebox.size();i++)
                {
                    if(BoxServer.messagebox.get(i).getReceiver().equals(senderOfSystemUse) && BoxServer.messagebox.get(i).getDeliver()!=true)
                    {
                        tempInbox.add(BoxServer.messagebox.get(i));
                        BoxServer.messagebox.get(i).delivered();
                    }
                }

             //   System.out.println("قاعدتا باید نوشته باشه :دی");
                outp.writeObject(tempInbox);


            }
            else
            {
                //System.out.println("ye payam be sistem ezaf shod :"+mess);
                BoxServer.messagebox.add(mess);
            }

            }
            //mySocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //System.out.println("bug dar thread");
            System.exit(0);
            //e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                mySocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.exit(0);
            //  e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

         }

    }
}
```

my client code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    /**
     * @param args
     */



    public String userTemp;
    public Main()
    {








        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JPanel jpanel=new JPanel(null);
        this.getContentPane().add(jpanel);
        JButton inbox=new JButton("INBOX");
        jpanel.add(inbox);
        inbox.setBounds(0,0,100,30);
        inbox.setToolTipText("for see your inbox messages click!");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(400,400);
        JLabel receiver=new JLabel("receiver : ");
        jpanel.add(receiver);
        receiver.setBounds(0,60,100,30);
        final JTextField receiverText=new JTextField();
        jpanel.add(receiverText);
        receiverText.setBounds(100,60,100,30);
        receiverText.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        JLabel message=new JLabel("message : ");
        jpanel.add(message);
        message.setBounds(0, 90, 100, 30);
        final JTextArea messageText=new JTextArea();
        jpanel.add(messageText);
        messageText.setBounds(100,90,200,30);
        messageText.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        ImageIcon x=new ImageIcon("send.png");
        JButton send=new JButton(x);
        jpanel.add(send);
        send.setBounds(50,130,64,64);
        final JTextField username=new JTextField("username ...");
        JButton signup=new JButton("new user");
        signup.setVisible(false);
        JButton login=new JButton("login Or create");
        jpanel.add(login);
        jpanel.add(signup);
        jpanel.add(username);
        username.setBounds(10,240,100,40);
        login.setBounds(10, 290, 200, 50);
        signup.setBounds(110, 290, 100, 50);
        //kpanel
        final JPanel kpanel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        kpanel.setBackground(Color.green);
        ImageIcon t=new ImageIcon("back.png");
        JButton back=new JButton(t);
        kpanel.add(back);
        back.setBounds(0,0,64,64);  
        kpanel.setVisible(false);
    //  this.getContentPane().add(kpanel);


        try {

            username.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String teString=username.getText();
                    if(teString.equals("username ..."))
                    {
                        username.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });

            final Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",79); 
            final ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            final ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());



                    try {
                        System.out.println("ghable khundane shomaarash");

                        int temp=in.readInt();//*********//

                        System.out.println("baade khundane shomaarash");

                        userTemp=""+temp;
                        login.setText(userTemp);

                        Thread timer=new Thread()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                while(true)
                                {
                                    Message temp=new Message();
                                    temp.setReceiver("system-use:code=1");
                                    temp.setSender(userTemp);

                                    try {
                                        out.writeObject(temp);
                                        sleep(60000);
                                    } 
                                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                    //  e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        //e.printStackTrace();
                                        try {
                                            socket.close();
                                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        };
                        timer.start();





                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    //      System.out.println("socket can not close");
                        }
                    //  e1.printStackTrace();
                    }












            Thread readerMessagesFromServer=new Thread(){

                public void run()
                {
                    while(true)
                    {

                        try {
                            ArrayList<Message> inboxReceived;

                            inboxReceived = (ArrayList<Message>) in.readObject();
                        //  System.out.println(userTemp+" received in its box :"+inboxReceived.size());
                            for(int i=0;i<inboxReceived.size();i++)
                            {
                                kpanel.add(new JLabel(inboxReceived.get(i).toString()));


                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                            try {

                                socket.close();
                                in.close();
                                out.close();

                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            };

            readerMessagesFromServer.start();

            send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    String rec=receiverText.getText();
                    String mes=messageText.getText();
                    String snd=userTemp;
                    Message obj=new Message();
                    obj.setReceiver(rec);
                    obj.setSender(snd);
                    obj.setText(mes);

                    try {
                        out.writeObject(obj);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });

        } catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }



        inbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                jpanel.setVisible(false);
                kpanel.setVisible(true);
                Main.this.getContentPane().add(kpanel);


            }
        });

        back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                kpanel.setVisible(false);
                Main.this.getContentPane().remove(kpanel);
                jpanel.setVisible(true);

            }
        });




    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {



        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Main ex = new Main();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: Please use your shift key at the start of every sentence, and for the word I and proper names.  Reading all lower case is like listening to somebody mumble.

Comment: Hint: For more and faster answers provide some [SSCCE](http://homepage1.nifty.com/algafield/sscce.html) instead of 400 lines of code.

Comment: -1 This question shows zero effort to isolate the problem down to a few relevant lines of code. Pasting in great slabs of code is not welcome here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call flush() after calling writeInt(). You should also construct the ObjectOutputStream before the ObjectInputStream.

Comment: Thank you.Now it is ok but before i didn't use flush for object transfer over socket.Is flush only for primitive types or some other things?

Comment: @Sina Correct. `ObjectOutputStream` runs an internal buffer that gets flushed after `writeObject()` but not after writing primitives.